# Example of BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

I know how spring `BeanPostProcessor` works but I exactly don't get any such scenarios where `BeanPostProcessor` might be very helpful. If someone has implemented `BeanPostProcessor` in his/her application, then please give a brief about that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) interface is arguably the most basic and useful tool of the Spring IoC container. Take a look at the implementing classes in the javadoc.

You typically use Spring to inject beans into other beans. Spring uses [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) to achieve this. After the bean has been instantiated, this `BeanPostProcessor` scan the bean's fields for `@Autowired` targets. If it finds any, it tries to resolve a bean from the context to inject. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java).